# Are there processors on which VPMASKMOVD generates faults for the masked-out elements?

Tags: assembly, x86, avx2, amd-processor

Are there processors on which `VPMASKMOVD` generates faults for the masked-out elements?

Going by the Intel Software Developer's Manual, the answer is plainly "no":

> Faults occur only due to mask-bit required memory accesses that caused the faults. Faults will not occur due to referencing any memory location if the corresponding mask bit for that memory location is 0. For example, no faults will be detected if the mask bits are all zero.

However, AMD64 Architecture Programmer's Manual volume 4 says:

> Exception and trap behavior for elements not selected for loading or storing from/to memory is implementation dependent. For instance, a given implementation may signal a data breakpoint or a page fault for doublewords that are zero-masked and not actually written.

Are there processors that actually do that? Is this bogus? What's up with this.

Comment: I have never relied on that. It's a silly instruction, you should not need that nonsense. The instruction is as slow as molasses. You have SIMD stuff where it doesn't know about alignment? Sounds like you are using SIMD for non-SIMD. Sensible use of SIMD involves SoA or AoSoA. You should use a load and a blend to mask.

Comment: @doug65536 I do not recall the last time I used this operation, nevertheless its semantics should be clarified.

Comment: @doug65536: The load form is single-uop on AMD Zen 2 and later, 2 uops on Intel (https://uops.info/).  The store form is also efficient on Intel, but not AMD.  (Not even Zen 4 where AVX-512 masked stores *are* efficient.)  One common reason for SIMD with possibly-misaligned data is auto-vectorization by compilers, where the compiler hasn't been promised alignment even if the program does align.  Or because people didn't make such a big deal about it, since it only makes a small speed difference (a couple %) with 256-bit vectors for data coming from L2, L3, or DRAM, on Intel since Haswell.

Comment: @doug65536: ISA designers seem to think compilers would want masking instead of scalar cleanup.  It would probably be better in simple cases if it's efficient. (Including the cost of generating masks from `count & 7` or whatever, which x86 doesn't have nice support for with AVX2 due to lack of vector shuffles / byte-shifts with one scalar the control, although `bzhi(-1, count & 7)` / `kmov` can be ok with AVX-512.)  Anyway, SIMD is so good on modern x86 that it's useful for more than just trivial vertical problems with nice data layouts.  Unaligned vector load/store support is quite good.

Comment: https://travisdowns.github.io/blog/2019/06/11/speed-limits.html mentions some about the cost of extra L1d cache accesses, so yes alignment is important for data already hot in L1d cache where you don't have many ALU ops per load/store.  (This is all off-topic and should probably be moved to chat.)

Comment: @doug65536 I only do SIMD for non-SIMD things.  That's where it's the most fun.